# AC_CHECK_LIB(asan, _init) succeeds for some reason

Tags: c++, c, linux, autoconf

I am trying to figure out how `AC_CHECK_LIB([asan], [_init], ,[...])` succeeds despite the source for `asan` not having a symbol called `_init`.

I verified the symbols by using `nm -D /path/to/libasan`. There is only one matching symbol called `__asan_init`.

Shouldn't autoconf fail with error saying it is unable to locate symbol `init` in the said library?

Regards

Comment: why not use the right way to illustrate what you are doing?

Comment: Sorry, did it now.

Comment: Is the `libasan.so` you check is the one use by your compiler? I see that `_init` is present for gcc7, but not for gcc8

Comment: Doesn't `AC_CHECK_LIB` just test link a program which references the symbol `_init` against `libasan`? Of course, that test link will succeed if any other library (such as the standard library) provides the symbol `_init`. I guess you are supposed to check for a symbol very specific to `libasan` to actually check for the presence of `libasan`.